# OneDrive sync files to local computer

Tags: windows-8.1, download, copy-paste, onedrive

How can I get OneDrive in Windows 8.1 to download all my files to a folder to my machine and keep them synced? I can view the files but can't copy them anywhere else using the windows copy and paste function.

When copying and pasting it get stuck on 0% and never moves.

Comment: It already does that.  Just look at the OneDrive folder in Explorer.

Comment: No its all "online" it does not download the files till you use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Windows Explorer

Navigate to your OneDrive folder, right-click on the file or folder you wish to download and select "Make available offline".

To download all your files, right-click on OneDrive in the left-hand navigation bar and select the same option.

---

#### OneDrive app

Right-click on any file or folder you wish to download and select "Make offline" from the app bar at the bottom.

To download all your files, you can either:

- Right-click in empty space to show the app bar, click on "Select all", then "Make offline", or
- Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to show the Settings menu, go to Options and enable the "Access all my OneDrive files offline" option. This will also show you how much disk space is needed to download all files.

Comment: Win + I does not give me an "options menu"

Comment: Win+I should show the Settings menu, from which you can open the Options menu (in addition to things like Help, About, Permissions etc). If that doesn't work for you, then press Win+C to open the Charms bar and from there select Settings.

Comment: I don't have an options menu. even on the charms bar. Where is the "Access all my OneDrive files offline" at?

Comment: Did you open the OneDrive app? In the Charms bar there should be a gear icon with the word Settings under it. Click that. It should open a new menu where the first entry is Options. Click that. That's where that offline option is.

Comment: Look, does this GIF help? http://i.stack.imgur.com/vigAC.gif

Comment: Yes it does I was not on the app my fault sorry and thanks! lets hope this works!

Comment: Okay, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Open the OneDrive immersive application, then open settings (<kbd>Start</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>), select Options and set the “Make my files available offline” switch (the top one). It may take a while to download the files.

Comment: Start + X does not give me an "Options Menu also"

Comment: I can't tell why some shortcuts might not work, but one way or another, Settings for a fullscreen app should be at the bottom of the Charms bar (the one that expands from the right side)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, right-click the OneDrive cloud icon in the system tray and select Settings. On the **Settings** tab in the OneDrive pop-up menu, uncheck the Files On-Demand option to save space and download files as you use them. On the **Account** tab, click to Choose folders. You'll find an option there to Download all folders or something like that. I can't check now, because I already did that and the Choose folders button is grayed out.